# How to upload and download a file with the given path(already known) without using html form in servlet using post method?

Tags: java, servlets

I know solution of the above problem using HTML form in which user chooses a file from computer and upload it and then download it but how to do it without using HTML with the already given path of file.

Thank you For your concern in Advance.

Comment: Using post method without html form. is it possible?

Comment: If that were possible, all web servers being able to access client's disk file system unaskingly, Internet would have looked very differently.

Comment: What about peer to peer architecture ?

Comment: HTTP/HTML is not a tool suitable for that architecture. If it really needs to be webbased for some odd design reason, look for HTML-embeddable applications like Applets.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the scenario is that the user accesses your server from a browser.

In this case you will not be able to access the file system given file paths. Only the user can grant access to certain files by selecting them in a file upload input.

If the user uses a mobile/desktop application that sends the file to your server, you must implement the upload in the app itself.